# Excel - Average IF with an Offset

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to write a formula that will Average every other cell in Row 7 starting from a 1 column offset of cell H7. I have the first part working great, but the offset is giving me trouble.

This formula works great to Average every other cell

```
{=AVERAGE(IF((I7:GQ7<>"")*(MOD(COLUMN(I7:GQ7),2)=1),I7:GQ7))}
```

But when we insert a new column from Column I, the formula doesn't include the new inserted column.  I'm hoping using a offset from column H will fix this problem.

This is a scoring tracker that will be updated daily, it contains 25 rows and a bunch of columns. Everyday 2 new columns will be inserted, from Column I.  I'm hoping to make it so the formulas include the new columns without requiring daily formula edits.

One variation to the formula, I'd like to include would be to average the last 30 as well.  Thank you for any help you can provide.

Comment: I really appreciate your help, thank you for taking the time.  That was almost what I needed, very smart, but this sheet is a sortable list and the rows will change positions.  The Indirect method locks down the starting cell.  I want to use an Offset from column H instead.  I'm not sure how to construct the formula for a Average, IF, Offset.   Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Following formula approach will hold it on I7. To be committed by <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd> as it is an Array formula.

`=AVERAGE(IF((INDIRECT("I7"):GQ7<>"")*(MOD(COLUMN(INDIRECT("I7"):GQ7),2)=1),INDIRECT("I7"):GQ7))`

However, `INDIRECT` function is volatile and therefore may result in performance hit if it is being used extensively.